# Make an element "slide" to the left. Like a slider

Tags: jquery, slider, mouseevent, css-position, slide

Basically I'm trying to create a simple version of the "Smooth Scroll plugin" due to it being to heavy for my simple needs. I have little experience in jQuery and I was wondering how you'd make an element's left attribute decrease while  the mouse is over another element.

```
$('.fade_right').live('mouseover', function() {
    //Tell code to go left
});
```

Looked around and even at the source of the smooth scroll plugin but I can't work it out. Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a complete, simple demo page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Simple scrolling div demo</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var intervalId;
            var scrollingSpeed = 16;    //the lesser, the faster; but don't use less than 16
            var pixelStep = 2;          //eventually, you want to increase this value for higher speed

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.fade_right').mouseenter(function() {
                    intervalId = setInterval(stepToLeft, scrollingSpeed);
                });

                $('.fade_right').mouseleave(function() {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                });

                function stepToLeft() {

                    var scrollingDiv = $('#scrollingDiv');
                    var x = parseInt(scrollingDiv.css('left'));
                    scrollingDiv.css('left', (x - pixelStep) + "px");

                }

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scrollingDiv" style="position: relative; background-color: #000; color: #fff; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 0px;">test</div>
        <div class="fade_right" style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 100px;">Move to left</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

More about setInterval and clearInterval functions [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

Comment: This works better then any other answer, but the tradition is jumpy and not a continuous motion. Also when leaving the element the transition continues.

Comment: Looks good but how would you construct the stepToLeftFunction for this particular piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. There's an example right on that page which does (almost) exactly what you're looking for.

---

If you want it to continuously animate, you'll want to use a `while` loop in conjunction with `mouseenter`; so long as `mouseleave` has not been called, you'll want to continuously execute the loop. It may be easier to use the Javascript `onmouseout` call rather than `mouseleave`. As the familiar phrase goes, I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: The issue is I want it to continuously scroll sideways until the user takes the mouse of the $('.fade_right') element.

Comment: With while you can loop a function, but you have no control over the speed of the cycle, whose speed it is just related to CPU power. Especially with graphic functions, you want to have control on the speed animation, that's why i would certainly go for a setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can use mouseenter event, in addition to the animate function.

Try this:

```
$('.fade_right').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The issue is I want it to continuously scroll sideways until the user takes the mouse of the $('.fade_right') element.

Answer (score 0):

Not using live, but uses `hover()` to trigger the left `animate` call and then on mouse out resets the view to the original position...

```
$('.fade_right').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "left": $(this).width() //just a simple way to make it fluid
    }, $(this).width() * 5); //some interval based upon the width for the time.
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        //Put it back to where it was...
        left: $(this).data("oldLeft")
    }, "fast");
}).data("oldLeft", $('.fade_right').css("left"));
```

Works ok in the example but hard to say depending on your needs.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Tgfuz/1/).**